# having trouble passing margins to Material UI using styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having trouble passing margin using mui styles to my components. Other styles are being passed just fine however when I try margins they do not seem to be applied to my site.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tool: {
    width:'100%',
    display: 'inline-flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  lastBtn: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 50,
  }
})
```

This is the definition before my function. Inside my function I have definted classes the following way.

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

Inside my main component i added

```
className={classes.root}
```

and it works just fine, so I know the issue is not styles hook. However the issue is that the same logic is not working for the button component. When I try doing the margins are not being applied.

```
<Button
  className={classes.lastBtn}
  variant='contained' 
  size='large' 
  onClick={() => navigate("/register")}
>
  Register
</Button>
```

When i try to replace the styles hook declared earlier it is working just fine.

```
style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 50}}
```

Can anyone spot the mistake I am making? I have done tons of research and I am stuck with debugging this. It is very inefficient to use inline styling to create margins for my whole project.

Thank you

Comment: You could try adding units (assuming you wanted pixels): `marginLeft: '10px'`.

Comment: Yes I tried that too still did not work

Comment: You could also inspect the resulting markup with the browser dev tools and see what styles are generated for your button. That might give you some clues about the origin of the problem.